# How are are data types extended and converted in operations in mysql/sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, types, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I am not clear how the mathematical operations are done in SQL.
For example in Java the numbers are "extended" to integers before applying an operation and when the other operand is of higher type or diffent precision we get conversions. Same in C++.
But what happens in SQL? Is there a default type that they are "extended" regardless if the underlying data type and we get same kind of conversions?

**Update:**
I also have the following example:

```
mysql> select sum from float_test;    
+-------+  
| sum   |  
+-------+  
| 59.95 |  
+-------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)    

mysql> select sum*(0.2) from float_test;  
+--------------------+  
| sum*(0.2)          |  
+--------------------+  
| 11.990000152587891 |  
+--------------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`sum` is a float so it is displayed with 2 digit precision but it is stored differently (due to rounding errors inherent in floats etc).
When I multiply with 0.2 I get this number.
I understand that it is due to using a float but why does it show so many digits and not just 2 i.e. 11.99 like the first SELECT that shows 59.95 (although 59.95000002322 something is stored)?

Comment: Please have a look at the chapters [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html) and [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html) of the manual.

Comment: @VMai:Thanks for the links. I will read them. Please see my update in OP